# jquery - Selectors not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to add like functionality to my site using jQuery but my element selectors aren't working.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="btn-like" id="1">2</a>
```

**JQUERY(HTML NOT WORKING):**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-like").click(function() {
    var like_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('a.btn-like#'+like_id).html('Loading ...');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "like.php",
      data: 'item_id='+like_id,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('a.btn-like#'+like_id).html(data);
        alert(data); //correct response
        $('a.btn-like#'+like_id).addClass('liked');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

**JQUERY(HTML WORKING):**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-delete").click(function() {
    var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('a.btn-delete#'+item_id).html('Loading ...');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "post.php",
      data: 'item_id='+item_id,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('div#post_'+item_id).remove();
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

The response of the ajax post is correct. But the `.html` update is not working

The content is not changed after clicking the link.

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Cant you use just `$(this).html('Loading...');` ?

Comment: At the other function that works the `.html` works fine. Only i that code not

Comment: why don't you just use $(this).html('Loading .... ') ?

Comment: Did you also change to `$(this).html(data);`? Btw, does the "Loading..." work? And i don't suppose this is another case of multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: I also add an variabel after the item_id var called `var btn = $(this);` Later in the code i used only `btn.html('Loading ...');`

Answer (score 0):

For an anchor tag, you should be updating the text property.

`$('a.btn-like#'+like_id).text(data);`

Comment: Sorry that is not working. Also the same code at an other function with other Variables works fine. But this is not working

Comment: can you add an error function?
```,error: function(data) {
        alert(data); //correct response
    }```

Comment: That I tested to but the ajax post have success so he can only not update the `html` code if the element. Everything else works fine